# How do I keep a small space within a two-word name when using justification in html?

Tags: html, css, typography, justify

So when I write "Meyer Waterlow is a fantastic company" and also use css justification, the gaps between all words get treated equally. So I might get

```
"Meyer    Waterlow    is    a    fantastic    company"
```

Instead, I'd like

```
"Meyer Waterlow     is     a     fantastic    company".
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Put `Meyer Waterlow` in a span? Did you try anything at all yet?

Comment: @Oded, there is no reason to assume that putting the words in a span would have an effect. This is a real question, and there is really nothing *obvious* to try.

Comment: What styling is already applied to that content?  What is your markup?

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach  is to use a non-breaking space in between the words...

```
Meyer&nbsp;Waterloo
```

Of course, it all depends on how the text is being generated, from a database or hand coded.

Comment: This used to be the solution, and it still works on IE 10, but in Chrome and Firefox, it does not have the desired effect. And no specification says that the no-break space should not expand in justification – browsers just used to treat it as a fixed-width space. Besides, it also has its defined meaning: it glues words together so that browsers may not divided them into two lines, and this is usually an undesired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid there is no direct solution, since the no-break space does not work reliably as a “non-stretchable” space as it used to.

Here’s a hackish trick: leave no space between the words, but put a zero-width space between them (acting as an allowed line breaking point) and set a right padding on the first word:

```
<span class=word>Meyer</span>&#x200b;Waterlow
```

with CSS code

```
.word { padding-right: 0.25em; }
```

The value `0.25em` roughly approximates the *average* width of a space character (but the width actually varies considerably by font).